# ASK CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: html, mysql, css, sql

i have a query in mysql using concat :

[image: query]

ouput : [image: output]

i want the ouput is **Lutron GL Ltd**

what's wrong guys ?

Thanks

Comment: Bold formatting is part of the user interface (presentation), and has nothing to do with SQL. The user interface interprets that formatting, and we have no idea how you're presenting the data from your query. A `SELECT` returns the data; it's up to you to present it to the user. (So the answer is: Nothing is wrong with your query. You're asking the wrong question. It's like saying "I have words in my head. Why are they blue instead of red on the paper?" when we have no idea how they got from your brain to the page.)

Comment: I would agree. i would use the database only to pull data and use a programming language like php or ruby to do all the formatting.

Comment: @all,thanks for your advice.in server side im using kohana helper select() for generated select form html (<?php echo Form::select('supp_clsf', $clsf,0,array('id'=>'supp_clsff_select')); ?> because the $clsf is array i cant modified to bold result company_name.

Comment: Your question is _"How can I style a `<option>` element."_ ([which has an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)), not anything that has to do with (my)sql.

Answer (score 0):

you want style `Lutron GL Ltd` with mysql `?

remove  tags from mysql and use them when you output the results like that

```
     echo "<option class='bold' value='....' >".$row['cn_clsf']."</option>" ;
```

Just use CSS to make it BOLD.